# Why not add the date in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aHeH.png)

```
    ERROR: column "date" is of type date, and the expression - integer
    LINE 3: VALUES (1, 1, 05.10.2015, 1);

                           ^
HINT: Rewrite the expression or convert its type.
```

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/BfJk95E.png)

Comment: You likely have to wrap the date in quotes, as it stands it says "2015 minus  10 minus 5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date literals are specified using the `date` keyword followed by the date in ISO format:

```
DATE '2015-10-05'
```

If you really want to use a different format, you need to use the `to_date()` function:

```
to_date('05.10.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

More details in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT